# Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) further clarification

Tags: intel, haxm

I've browsed through the different answers related to this matter but I still don't get it. I've tried these following solutions:
1. "I am sorry, I forget to answer this question. After few days of googling I found, that problem was caused by hyperthreading (or hyper - v). I decided to edit my boot.ini file with option to start up windows with hyperthreading turned off. I followed this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry.aspx and now everything works perfect"

2. "Just follows these steps:

Go to Control Panel → Program and Feature.
Click on Turn Window Features on and off. A window opens.
Uncheck Hyper-V option and restart your system.
Now, you can Start HAXM installation without any error."

Here are the problems related to those solutions:
1. For this solution, in my command prompt, there is no line for "hypervisorlaunchtype".

2. For this solution, there is no Hyper-V option available.

By the way,my computer supports Virtualization Technology. I've used Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility to know this thing. Anyone, please help me.

Comment: Your cpu may support it, but your pc maker may have disabled VT-x in the bios.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: reboot, go into the bios, and see if your machine has a toggle for the option there. if not, then you need a new machine, or a new bios.

Comment: what CPU do you have?  What OS?

Comment: CPU - I5
OS - Windows 7

Answer (score 6):

From a command line as admin - type

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and

```
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
```

Make sure you don't have Avast running with Enable hardware-assisted virtualization on.

Comment: Sir, I did what you had advised yet I still get an error saying "This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled. Please refer to the Intel HAXM Documentation for more information."

Comment: did you reboot afterwards?

Comment: Did you install the pack for windows 7 to add hyperV? http://blogs.technet.com/b/schadinio/archive/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7.aspx

Comment: Yes, I rebooted. And I've already installed the pack for windows 7 to add hyperV, and then when I tried it, it still didn't work. Still the same message pops out. "his computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled. Please refer to the Intel HAXM Documentation for more information" I need help :(

Comment: actually I was wrong - as long as you're on windows 7 you can only install the manager but to have hyper-v you have to have server 08 or win 8.x or the win 10 tech preview (which you could try)......

Comment: The `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` step was the one I had been missing.