# error when Installing Intel-Haxm on a virtual Machine (Created under Hyper-V Windows Server 2012)

Tags: android-studio, intel, hyper-v, haxm

I try to insaller  intel-haxm on a virtual machine ( Windows 8.1) created under  hyper-v  windows 2012 I disabled the hyper-v  functionality of windows 
but the setup gives me the following error

> This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. 
>   Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.

i have an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v2 @ 250 Ghz
and the VT Technology is enabled on the BIOS
Are there any a sollution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834445/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat?rq=1

Comment: I tried all the sokution listed in the poste  without success. in my case the virtual machine is created by Hyper-V's will not be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The HAXM in the virtual machine running on Hyper-V cannot get access to the Intel VT extensions. Basically, these extensions cannot be emulated by Hyper-V and it does not allow the VM to access them neither.

Hyper-V supports *nested virtualization* with Hyper-V, i.e. a Hyper-V running in a VM on Hyper-V can get access to the VT extensions. Other hypervisors such as HAXM cannot run on nested virtualization on Hyper-V.

Note that other hypervisors such as VmWare support emulation of the VT extensions. Although I have not tried, it is very possible that you can run HAXM in a VM on these hypervisors.